# How to retrieve particular ID elements within a web page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unsure how to approach this for the web page that I am on (i.e. in my web app) using jQuery. I would like to be able to add to an array in order of appearance through the web page, all elements where the id matches the string "_AB_Q_"

For example, scattered through the web page will be instances of the following:

```
<id="P1_AB_Q_101">...
<id="P1_AB_Q_102">...
<id="P1_AB_Q_103">...
<id="P1_AB_Q_104">... 
..
...
....
<id="P1_AB_Q_500">...
```

As mentioned, I only want to retrieve full id names where the id matches the pattern "_AB_Q_" and then store these in an array for later processing.

So using the test data above, I want to only return:

```
P1_AB_Q_101
P1_AB_Q_102
P1_AB_Q_103
P1_AB_Q_104 
P1_AB_Q_500
```

Comment: Your HTML example looks like cr*p :P

Comment: That it does but didn't think I needed to copy and paste a whole heap of unnecessary tags that were not related to my question.

Comment: Did you find any answer useful? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the attribute contains selector:
Ive created a Jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/whizkid747/D2HS4/

```
$('[id*="_AB_Q_"]').each(function(){
    alert(this.getAttribute('id'));
});
```

documentation: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: This works fine but at the same time I need to ignore any elements that return as "_AB_Q_nnnn_fieldset" - so basically
any element that has a "_fieldset" I want to ignore from my return list. Thanks.

Comment: This requirement is not in your question above :). so what you are asking here is that if the id is P1_AB_Q_104_fieldset or P1_AB_Q_120_field set, then you need to ignore them?

Comment: If I understood you right, here is the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/whizkid747/D2HS4/1/

Comment: Thanks Whizkid747 - apologies that this is not in the original question but only noticed it when I ran your code over it. I managed to target it to a particular class but also appreciate your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id^="_AB_Q_"]').each(function(){
     console.log(this.getAttribute('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [attribute contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector and the [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function;

`var ids = $('[id*="_AB_Q_"]').map(function() { return this.id });`

*Not tested but it should work :)*

Answer (score 0):

My approch would be:

```
var ids = []
$("*").each(function(){
    if(this.id.match(/_AB_Q_/))
        ids.push(this.id)
});
```

is more or less the same as the other onces, but i seperated the match condtion, to make it easy to adapt. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$('[id^=_AB_Q_]').doSomeAction();
```

It checks if an id starts with the string provided.

JQuery selectors are css selectors. For a complete list you should check [http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.htm](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

edit:

```
// if the id = AB_Q_P1_100
// you can retrieve different parts of the id like this
var parts = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
var p = parts['3'];
```

Comment: substring inside the id needs to be checked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the string part I want to match does not begin with "AB_Q_" - it is actually in the middle part of the id. I want to match this string but return the full name that contains it. Thanks.

Comment: If your id's are added with php or any other server side language you could change the order.